# Access files stored in Cloud9 from a local machine

Tags: matlab, ftp, cloud9-ide

I am a [cloud9](http://c9.io/) user, and I'm using it to provide a ready-to-go platform that can be used by other (unexperienced) users. Currently, these users are using an external program (i.e. matlab) to see the results of the computations. This involves a quite cumbersome copy-paste of files from the c9 workspace to the local machine in which they can run the matlab code. Is there a better way to do that? I have seen that if you right click on a folder in the workspace there is the **create a mount** option for that folder, but there is no documentation whatsoever either in the c9 website or in the web.

I would definitely love having access to those files through FTP, but I cannot uderstand how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The "create a mount" feature has gone silently live yesterday. We are testing it and fixing some bugs before announcing it and providing docs. If you can wait a few days, it will be available to you. Be sure to follow us on twitter or check our blog for the announcement.

Comment: Thanks ruben for the info. Any update regarding this? I didn't notice anything useful on the blog.

Comment: We're debugging some issues reported by the beta users. As soon as they are fixed we'll launch the feature.